# Regex in Java (Regular Expression and Grammar)

Tags: java, regex

That is my problem: I got an assignment due tomorrow (I have been working on it for the past days) and I think a got half of it, but the other half I just got a slight clue. Basically, I have to write a code where the user gives me some words and their categories (like a dictionary) and a grammar e.g.:

```
A: article adjective A  
A: adjective B  
B: noun
```

then the user will input a sentence and I will check if the words are in my dictionary, if so I will output their category and "Accept" if it matches the grammar and "Refuse" if it doesn't match.

Now, I know that I probably will have to use regex but I didn't find anything that really helped so far.
I will give a example of input and output:

```
Input:  
Dictionary:  
word: The  
category: article  
word: big  
category: adjective  
word: blue  
category: adjective  
word: car   
category: noun

Grammar:  
A: article adjective A  
A: adjective B  
B: noun  

Sentences:   
The big blue car  
The car big blue  

Output:  
(first sentence)  
article adjective adjective noun  
Accept  
(second sentence)  
article noun adjective adjective   
Refuse
```

So, my program is already outputting the correct categories but I don't know how to implement the grammar part (I already have a class with a arrayList for the grammar). As I said before, I think I will have to use Regex but didn't find that very helpful so far.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you already have a sentence parsed and mapped to categories, then you have no use for regex. You need to search through the grammar rules to see if you can find a combination that matches the categories.

Comment: Really? The problem is that I don't know how to go from the first A to the second A and then to B.

Comment: Think I will have to use tree. @Hiro2k just gave me that advice.

Comment: I guess, though I'd use a recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

Grammars are not usually implemented as regex since they are complex and self referencing, regex are more useful for parsing the incoming text. What you need is a better data structure than a list to represent the grammars and help you verify if a sentence is grammatically correct. Look into abstract syntax trees.

Comment: I was looking for trees in Java ( what I thought that would help me in first place) but just found binary tree what would not help. I will look up abstract syntax trees right away! Thanks

Comment: The Java standard library only has the most used data structures, AST's are very specific so you'll probably have to implement your own, which I'm guessing is the point of your assignment.

Comment: didn't find anything good so far, would you please recommend any article or tutorial?

Comment: The teacher didn't even specify the language we should use, some people are using C, for example. It might be difficult though, I didn't find good example anywhere so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generally implement a grammar with a regular expression, unless it is a grammar for a regular language, for example doesn't contain nested syntax such as

```
 expression: '(' expression ')'
```

You need a pushdown automaton of some kind, e.g. a recursive descent or LALR(1) parser.

See [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).